# Java Selenium: an example for profile.managed_auto_select_certificate_for_urls to select a certificate

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, certificate, registry

Is it possible to use `profile.managed_auto_select_certificate_for_urls`in java with Selenium?
I have to select a certificate in a list in order to do the login.
I can't change the registry key since i have multiple certificates.

If it's possible can you give me a hint of the code?
I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
Map<String, Object> pref = new Hashtable<>();
final String[] certs = new String[size()];
certs[index]=certificateString; 
pref.put("profile.managed_auto_select_certificate_for_urls",certs);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", pref);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).